# Combine space between text to hypen jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to know how to change  "how to learn python" to how-to-learn-python.php

My html code is

```
<input id='url' type='text'/>
```

My jquery code is

```
    $('#url').change(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "-"));
});
```

its given output like this "how-to-learn-python" , how i append .php in the last of the sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple string concatenation using `+` operator

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "-") + ".php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple string concatenation using `+` operator

```
$('#url').change(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "-") + ".php");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g,"_").replace("python","python.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple string concatenation as suggested by Adil.

Just out of curiosity, do you need to use this converted string in href for hyperlink, and your string might contain " or '? 
If yes, then it might break your HTML. Consider using encodeURIComponent for string and then use it as HREF value.